# Add collapse in accordion bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, accordion

How can I add more collapse itens in bootstrap accordion?
I tried do that based on bootstrap model. I just copied and pasted the correspondent div, but in this way don't worked.

I just change id name and aria-labelledby for headingfour. I think this is not enough.

Comment: you have to change every IDs except the main ID from the accordion - there are several.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
          Collapsible Group Item #1
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

id="accordion" stays the same.

id="headingOne" - for each panel

data-parent="#accordion" - stays the same

href="#IDFROMPANELBODY"

id="collapseOne" = IDFROMPANELBODY - for each panel

aria-labelledby - ID from "heading" (headingOne)

this is why:
the headingOne-ID is only for the label for aria, the href and the collapseOne-ID are the most important - without it won't work. the href needs to focus on the panel-body it's referred to. so the panel-collapse-div should have an own ID for every panel. and the href links to it.

here is an example how a second one would look like:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
          <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
              Collapsible Group Item #1
            </a>
          </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
          <div class="panel-body">
            Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```